# How many attempts does it take to get a perfect score on a T/F test, with only the score given as feedback?

Tags: combinatorics

(Based on a true story) I just took a quiz. One multiple choice question was also multiple answer (as in "select all that apply"). It had 6 possible options (A-F), with 4 of them being correct. Somehow, I managed to choose 2 correct and 2 incorrect options on each attempt, despite answering differently every time. Unfortunately, it doesn't show the correct answers, just the overall score of the question. Out of curiosity, is it possible to deduce what the correct answers were based on my scores and answers? How much data do we need to definitively score 100%? Is there an algorithm that allows us to solve this in a minimal number of attempts?

The provided answers range from A to F. Here were my answers:

- A, B, D, F - 2/4 correct
- A, C, E, F - 2/4 correct
- B, C, D, F - 2/4 correct

P.S. If we view choosing a letter as True and not choosing a letter as False, we can turn this into a T/F test with 6 questions.

Comment: Hi stranger, just wondering, why the downvote?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this problem is NP-complete by [known results about Mastermind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastermind_(board_game)#Complexity_and_the_satisfiability_problem)

Comment: I don't understand the data on your choices.  Were you to pick one choice that you hope is correct per question or were you to pick the four correct answers?  Does the first line represent your answer to the first question?  I thought you got to answer each question three times.  Or are these your three attempts on one question?  Were you given the best score of three attempts on each question, or did you have to pick the same run through for all three questions?

Comment: @diracdeltafunk:  while that is correct it is not applicable.  We have one problem of a given size that we are asked to solve.  It doesn't matter how the complexity grows as a function of the number of questions.

Comment: Of course I didn't mean this fixed case is NP-complete :) Just making a general comment about this kind of problem in general.

Comment: My interpretation is this: there is a fixed $6$-bit binary number $b$ that you do not know. You have three chances to probe this number – for each attempt, you provide a $6$-bit binary number, and are told how many of the digits in your number agree with the digits of $b$. For example, if $b$ is $101111$ and you guess $011100$, the feedback would be "$2$". Is there an algorithm that allows you to determine the number $b$, regardless of which $6$-bit number it is?

Comment: The confusing part is "$2/4$ correct" -- @Ryan, is this what you meant? Or do you mean "$2/6$ correct"?

Comment: This would be a better question for puzzling.se but too easy for them.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk:  presumably the $2/4$ means that two of the four choices are correct.

Comment: ... that would make sense, thanks. What a strange way to grade a quiz! As you note, though, this makes the scores reported by OP impossible to achieve.

Comment: @RossMillikan Sorry to confuse you. I just got back from walking my dog. What I'm concerned about is this single question. Ignore the rest of the quiz. It is both multiple choice and multiple answer (select all that apply). there are 6 options (A-F) and four of these are correct.  I got to attempt the quiz three times.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming these are your three answers for one question, we can assess the fact that you got $6$ points total and ask how many points each answer would give you.  $E$ gives you just one point, $F$ gives you three, and all the others give you two.  That means either both $E$ and $F$ are correct or neither one is because the sum has to be even.  If neither one is, $A,B,C,D$ are all correct and the first answer would give you three points, so they are both correct.  The second tells us that $A,C$ are both wrong, so the answer is $B,D,E,F$.  That fails because the first and third would give three points.  The conclusion is there is no way to select four correct answers that would give $2$ points on all three responses.

A simple way to see this is if you get only $2$ correct, the other two choices are correct.  The first tells us that $C,E$ are correct, the second that $B,D$ are correct, and the last that $A,E$ are correct.  Now we are told that all five except $F$ are correct, but you said that four were correct.  Contradiction.

Comment: Interesting Ross! I double checked and yep those are the answers and I received 1.5/3 points for that question every time.  I went about the same logic when I re-attempted the quiz, but I guess that's how I ended up so puzzled. I assumed each correct is worth 0.75 points. I would not be surprised if she messed up the quiz or gave us misinformation. Also a possibility is that "partially correct" is worth 1.5 no matter what combination of answers...